# bq CLI says my JSON schema is invalid while the browser GUI says it's fine. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a JSON schema:

[{"name":"timestamp","type":"integer"},{"name":"xml_id","type":"string"},{"name":"prod","type":"string"},{"name":"version","type":"string"},{"name":"distcode","type":"string"},{"name":"origcode","type":"string"},{"name":"overcode","type":"string"},{"name":"prevcode","type":"string"},{"name":"ie","type":"string"},{"name":"os","type":"string"},{"name":"payload","type":"string"},{"name":"language","type":"string"},{"name":"userid","type":"string"},{"name":"sysid","type":"string"},{"name":"loc","type":"string"},{"name":"impetus","type":"string"},{"name":"numprompts","type":"record","mode":"repeated","fields":[{"name":"type","type":"string"},{"name":"count","type":"integer"}]},{"name":"rcode","type":"record","mode":"repeated","fields":[{"name":"offer","type":"string"},{"name":"code","type":"integer"}]},{"name":"bw","type":"string"},{"name":"pkg_id","type":"string"},{"name":"cpath","type":"string"},{"name":"rsrc","type":"string"},{"name":"pcode","type":"string"},{"name":"opage","type":"string"},{"name":"action","type":"string"},{"name":"value","type":"string"},{"name":"other","type":"record","mode":"repeated","fields":[{"name":"param","type":"string"},{"name":"value","type":"string"}]}]

(http://jsoneditoronline.org/ for pretty print)

When loading through the browser GUI the schema is accepted as valid. The cli throws the following error:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Invalid schema entry: "fields":[{"name":"type"
```

Is there something wrong with my schema as specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the schema as json, you should write it to a file and pass the file name as the schema parameter. Passing the schema inline on the command line is only allowed for simple flat schemas.

Comment: Is it still the case?